# What is the reason that nginx throws a 403 error, with all permissions allowed?

Tags: docker, nginx

OS: macOS Monterey 
Chip: Apple M1

When starting a project in docker, nginx gives a 403 error when accessed in a browser, but at the same time, a colleague's project starts without any problems

[Nginx configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pdpd6.png) 
[Logs when opening a project in a browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6238.png) 
[Permissions for _default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMBYJ.png) 
[Rights for www and others](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHwFf.png)

```
resolver 127.0.0.11;
server
    {
        listen 80 default_server;
        server_name     _;
        root /var/www/_default/www/;
        pagespeed off;
        set $php_sock php:9000;
        # раскомментируйте одну из строчек ниже в зависимости от используемой cms
        # include common_fpm_ceteracms.conf;
        # include common_fpm_bitrix.conf;
        include common_fpm_<% PROJECT_CMS_TYPE %>.conf;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
        location /nginx_status
            {
                stub_status on;
                allow ::;
                deny all;
            }

        # заментие off на on если надо включить pagespeed
}
```

```
root@c312a39869da:/var/www/_default# ls -l
total 16
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   67 Mar 15 08:12 Makefile
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  410 Mar 15 08:12 README.md
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Mar 15 14:52 boilerplate
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root  128 Mar 15 08:12 tmp
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Mar 15 14:52 working
drwxrwxrwx 4 root root  128 Mar 15 08:12 www
```

```
root@c312a39869da:/var/www# ls -lna
total 16
drwxr-xr-x  1  0  0 4096 Mar 15 14:52 .
drwxr-xr-x  1  0  0 4096 Nov 22  2019 ..
drwxr-xr-x 15  0  0  480 Mar 15 08:12 _default
drwxrwxrwx  1 33 33 4096 Dec 15  2019 html
```

```
grd_nginx        | 2022/03/15 11:59:16 [error] 32#32: *2 directory index of "/var/www/_default/www/" is forbidden, client: 172.19.0.1, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "127.0.0.1:8080"
grd_nginx        | 172.19.0.1 - - [15/Mar/2022:11:59:16 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 117 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:98.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/98.0" "-"
```

Comment: can you paste text instead?

Comment: also check permissions for `/var/www/_default/www/` and its files?

Comment: `root@c312a39869da:/var/www/_default/www# ls -lna`

`total 4`


`drwxrwxrwx  4 0 0 128 Mar 15 08:12 .`
`drwxr-xr-x 15 0 0 480 Mar 15 08:12 ..`
-rw-r--r--  1 0 0 427 Mar 15 08:12 .gitignore
drwxr-xr-x  6 0 0 192 Mar 15 08:05 local
`

Comment: what page(url) are you requsting? is it static content or php?

Comment: Could you please disable SELinux and test. You need to check /var/log/audit log.

Comment: Request for /, .php